# Different ndk code for flavor

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-productflavors

I know how to run a different Java code for different flavors, and I have a Java class that implements the code I need for each flavor. However, what do I do if I want to implement a different C++ (NDK) for each flavor? How do I setup access to different class or h file for the flavors? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `targets` to select target libraries for each flavor in your build.gradle and define libraries in your CMakeLists.txt.

From guide https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds?hl=ja#pass-args-flags

```
productFlavors {
    ...
    demo {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                ...
                targets "native-lib-demo"
            }
        }
    }

    paid {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                ...
                targets "native-lib-paid",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To check which library is included, use Build > Analyze APK and look inside the lib directory.

Comment: Thank you. This was some time ago, and I will not be able to check this - but it sounds right, looks like the right way to go, so I'm accepting this.