# Android flavors - disable CMAKE for specific flavor

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-productflavors

I have two running types for my Android application, one that includes integration with a C++ library and the other one is not.

I want to create two flavors that will support that:

- **Flavor1** without NDK support. This flavor needs to run without any native code support, hence no native files needs to be part of the APK.
- **Flavor2** that supports the NDK, with the cmake path and version.

Is it possible to disable Cmake for only one flavor?

When I am trying to run flavor 1(no NDK) I'm getting an error (**:app:buildCMakeDebug[armeabi-v7a]**) that seems like cmake is still needed.

Below you can see the relevant lines from my Gradle file.

```
flavorDimensions "machine"
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        dimension "machine"
    }
    flavor2 {
        dimension "machine"
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        lbLibs "log"
    }
    externalNativeBuild.cmake {
        cppFlags ''
        }
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path file('src/flavor2/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
        version '3.18.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could do something similar to this and not include the NDK in the other flavor

```
flavorDimensions "machine"
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        dimension "machine"
    }
    flavor2 {
        dimension "machine"
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        lbLibs "log"
    }
    
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/flavor2/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.18.1'
            cppFlags ''
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Checkout the [Specify optional configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#pass-args-flags) in the docs

Comment: Actually I did something like that, it's not working - I'm getting an error.

Comment: This leaves 1 thing to try, Your original code was fine you could make the non paid version have an empty "target",  here's an answer on how it could be done, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080332/6151564 

Yet I still feel like you could make the original method, work somehow, Let me know how it goes

Comment: By Empty I mean, Make an NDK without logic for it

Comment: Currently I resolved it by sending a parameter and checked it in the CMAKE file.
In case the parameter equals to "flavor1" it immediately returns, but I'm sure there is a better solution.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach, reverse engineering can easily overcome this, read this article I wrote, (I have no experince in Cyber security) so imagine if someone who does did.  https://medium.com/@alanazi.saleh.77/a-practical-guide-to-the-dangerous-effects-of-reverse-engineering-on-android-applications-778035060c4f